# Android - How can i save image in specific folder using MediaStore.Images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

In my app image is directly saving to **Pictures** but I need to save the image in a specific folder like **Pictures/ClearScanner/img.jpg**, I have tried many solutions form StackOverflow and google android documents but I couldn't make any of them work so I am asking for help

**Utils.java**

```
    public class Utils {

    private Utils() {

    }

    public static Uri getUri(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {

        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        String foldername = "ClearScanner";
        String filename = "ClearScanner " + timeStamp + ".jpg";

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap, filename , null);
       // add the requested log statement after this line

       // add the requested log statement before this line
        return Uri.parse(path);

    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, Uri uri) throws IOException {
        return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219822/discussion-on-question-by-vamsee-android-how-can-i-save-image-in-specific-fol).